# SQL table size always increases

Tags: sql-server

I have a table having 5 column with **nvarchar(255)** datatype. in standard report  **reserved KB** was **12,74,576** and **Data** was **9,79,344**. when i changed all columns to **varchar(255)**, **reserved KB** was increased to **15,54,687** and **Data** was also increased. Then i re-changed the datatype of all columns to nvarchar(255) but the reserved KB and Data increased again. My problem is that whenever i change the datatype of columns, whether it is from **nvarchar** to **varchar** or vise versa, standard report shows that reserved KB and Data is increased.

Answer (score 0):

The size can be decreased by shrinking the database:

- Open SQL Server Management Studio
- Select the database
- Open the context menu
- Click Tasks
- Click Shrink
- Click Database

This can also be achieved by executing the `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` command.

When you want to reclaim space from a specific table, use the 'DBCC CLEANTABLE' command.

More information about the last command:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx

Comment: I would avoid doing this to a production database at all costs. This is incredibly dangerous to suggest as an option without also making sure they know they will experience massive amounts of fragmentation. Here is one of hundreds of articles on this topic. http://straightpathsql.com/archives/2009/01/dont-touch-that-shrink-button/

Comment: For production databases you have indeed to be careful. Considering the fact that Muhammad changes column datatypes, I assume it does not concern a production database.

Comment: My point is that when you offer a suggestion like this with HUGE potential issues you would make your answer more complete by communicating those caveats. If you assume this isn't production but in fact it is they may run this in production and then wonder why their whole system is now crippled.

Comment: I am not concerned about the size of database. My question is, why the table size increases when i change datatype from nvarchar to varchar.

Comment: DBCC is not decreasing size of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Nvarchar stores UNICODE data. If you have requirements to store UNICODE or multilingual data, nvarchar is the choice. Varchar stores ASCII data and should be your data type of choice for normal use. Regarding disk usage, nvarchar uses 2 bytes per character, whereas varchar uses 1.

Comment: i know that and that is why i am confused because by changing datatype from nvarchar to varchar, the table size must decrease whereas it increases.

Comment: It will not release the space without shrinking the files. DBCC shrink command.

Comment: in that case the size must be the same as before but why does it increase.